# Extracting distinct values from a table in excel but a zero kept showing in between my results?

Tags: excel

I'm trying to extract unique values from a list with empty cells in between in Excel. Currently, the formula I'm using is:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Raw List'!$D$5:$D$999,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($B$7:B7,'Raw List'!$D$5:$D$999),0)),"")
```

The 1st picture indicates the table (D5:D999) and the second picture is the target output. As you can see, the results is correct and it ignores duplicate values but then there's a "0" that keeps popping up and I'm not sure how to fix this.

Does anyone know what might cause this and how to fix the formula?

Thank you!

[image: Reference Table]

[image: Results Table]

Answer (score 1):

If you have Excel O365, with all the current functions, you can use the simpler formula:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(theRange,theRange<>""))
```

*Note that you still have to filter out the blanks.*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When the Countifs processes the range D5:D999 and gets as far as the first blank cell, it will return a count of zero, so you will get a match. Unfortunately, when Index refers to this blank cell it returns it as a zero, so that's where the zero comes from. You can fix it by checking that the current cell is non-blank as below. When the countifs runs out of non-blank non-duplicate cells, it will trigger the Iferror and return an empty string as expected.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Raw List'!$D$5:$D$999,MATCH(1,(COUNTIF($B$7:B7,'Raw List'!$D$5:$D$999)=0)*('Raw List'!$D$5:$D$999<>""),0)),"")
```

[image]